# KSQL create table from stream for latest data

Tags: ksqldb

I have a topic called customers and I have created a stream for it

```
CREATE STREAM customers_stream (customerId INT, isActive BOOLEAN)
  WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='customers', VALUE_FORMAT='json');
```

My producer for `customers` topic is generating a Integer key and a json value. But when I see the row key is being set to a some binary value

```
ksql> print 'customers';
Format:JSON
{"ROWTIME":1570305904984,"ROWKEY":"\u0000\u0000\u0003�","customerId":1001,"isActive":true}
{"ROWTIME":1570307584257,"ROWKEY":"\u0000\u0000\u0003�","customerId":1002,"isActive":true}
```

Now if i create a table it results in a single row (maybe because row key is the same??)

```
CREATE TABLE customers (customerId INT, isActive BOOLEAN)
  WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='customers', KEY='customerId',VALUE_FORMAT='json');
```

After searching the web I bumped into this article https://www.confluent.io/stream-processing-cookbook/ksql-recipes/setting-kafka-message-key and created a new stream by repartitioning on the key

```
CREATE STREAM customers_stream2 AS \
 SELECT * FROM customers_stream \
 PARTITION BY customerId;
```

So how do I create a table which has the latest values of customers data?

creating a table from stream is resulting in a error

```
CREATE TABLE customers_2_table_active AS
  SELECT CUSTOMERID,ISACTIVE
  FROM customers_stream2;
```

`Invalid result type. Your SELECT query produces a STREAM. Please use CREATE STREAM AS SELECT statement instead.`

I need the latest value of the various rows so that another microservice can query the new table.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rekeying seems to be the right approach, however, you cannot convert a `STREAM` into a `TABLE` directly.

Note, that your rekeyed stream `customers_stream2` is written into a corresponding topic. Hence, you should be able to crate a new `TABLE` from the stream's topic to get the latest value per key.

Comment: as a side note, do you know why the rowkey generated is such a value? is this a bug in kafka ?

Comment: What do you mean by "such a value"?

Comment: "ROWKEY":"\u0000\u0000\u0003�. Isnt the message key be stored as rowkey? If not then what is row key for?

Comment: Atm, ROWKEY in KSQL is always `String` type -- maybe you just deserialize it incorrectly?